# Aynchronous WebService call

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I have ASP.NET website, and it calls the asmx web-service to do some operation asynchronously

```
_service.Beginxxx(request, null, null);
```

which will run in separate thread (created by thread pool), what if the user close the browser, is this method still keep running and eventually do what I am expecting or it will abort?

Comment: What happened when you tried that? When you tested it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect it to keep running